# ReactJs route path including id returns incorrect components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to use Route to redirect to a component but it returns both components as below.

[image]

When it comes to /test/new i just want to display only NewRequest component.

I think the problem is the /:id/ but don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code for Route:

```
<div>                
    <Route exact path='/test/' render={(props) => <ViewList />} ></Route>
    <Route path='/test/new/' render={(props) => <NewRequest />} ></Route>
    <Route path='/test/:id/' render={(props) => <ViewDetail />} ></Route>
</div>
```

My question is how to fix the Route so it returns only NewRequest component? 
Thank you.

Comment: Add exact prop to `NewRequest` route.

Comment: By the way, you're not passing Route props to your components, either pass them to component prop `component={ViewList}` or spread the props `render={(props) => <ViewList {...props} />}`.

Comment: @IoannisPotouridis I actually have props in the <Route> but I remove them before posting as I think they are not the problems.

Comment: OK posted an answer, also don't forget to use `component` or spread the props because you won't have access to that `id` in `ViewDetail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `Route` components in `Switch`.

```js
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/test' component={ViewList} />
  <Route path="/test/new" component={NewRequest} />
  <Route path="/test/:id" component={ViewDetail} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: What about the line <Route exact path='/test/' ... ?

Comment: Adding it... :)

Comment: It works. Thanks mate. Any comment on how it's the fix?